# Can you specify multiple @Conditional annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

With Spring Boot, can one use multiple `@Conditional` annotations on one `@Bean` definition? If so, is there a predictable order that they are resolved? In other words, can I specify both `@ConditionalOnResource` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on the same `@Bean` def? Which one would take precedence?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.0.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Do you have any special reason that would make the order of conditional evaluations relevant?

Comment: No, you're right. Looking at my case again, the order is not important, so long as the behavior that Dave describes below is accurate, that should be fine for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think the order is important: any `Condition` that doesn't match will cause the bean to be omitted. If they all match, it will be included.

Comment: How can we define multiple @Conditional annotation in Spring 4.0?

Comment: Is it possible to express an OR relation such as `@ConditionalOnProperty` OR `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`?

Comment: Have a look at the javadoc for `AnyNestedCondition`